# Angular5 - Selector doesn't paint component.html when called from another component

Tags: selector, angular2-template

So I have two components, ChartsComponent (renders charts) &
DataComponent (displays charts among other data, tables, etc).

The file system would be like:

**app/charts/**

**app/entities/data/**

ChartsComponent renders successfully when rendered into its own page with its own route. DataComponent works but can't render ChartsComponent through selector. Console displays no error at all. I tried to call ChartsComponent's selector in DataComponent like this:

**data.component.html**:

```
<chart-data></chart-data>
```

**charts.component.html**:

```
<div [chart]="chart1"></div>
```

**charts.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';
//I'm loading data into the chart statically for trial
import { jsonData} from '../json-data/chart-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'chart-data',
  templateUrl: './charts.component.html'
})
export class ChartsComponent implements OnInit{

  //Chart
  chart1: Chart;
  countries: any;
  num: any;
  chartData: any;

  constructor() {
    this.barChart();
  }

  ngOnInit(){}

  barChart(){
    this.chartData = jsonData;
    this.chart1 = new Chart(this.chartData);
  }
}
```

**data.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from './provision.service';
import { ChartsComponent } from '../../charts/charts.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'data-page',
    templateUrl: './data.component.html'
})

export class DataComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

}
```

**charts.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ChartsComponent } from './';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ChartsComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        ChartsComponent
    ]
})

export class ChartsModule {}
```

**data.module.ts**:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ChartsModule } from '../../charts';
import { ChartsComponent } from '../../charts/charts.component';

import {
    DataService,
    DataComponent,
    DataRoute
} from './';

@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [DataComponent],
    entryComponents: [
        DataComponent,
        ChartsComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        DataService
    ]
})
export class DataModule {}
```

**charts/index.ts**:

```
export * from './charts.component';
export * from './charts.module';
export * from './charts.route';
```

**app.module.ts**:

```
import './vendor.ts';

import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Ng2Webstorage, LocalStorageService, SessionStorageService  } from 'ngx-webstorage';
import { EventManager } from 'ng-blahblah';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular-highcharts';
import { ChartsComponent } from './charts';


import { AuthInterceptor } from './blocks/interceptor/auth.interceptor';
import { AuthExpiredInterceptor } from './blocks/interceptor/auth-expired.interceptor';
import { ErrorHandlerInterceptor } from './blocks/interceptor/errorhandler.interceptor';
import { NotificationInterceptor } from './blocks/interceptor/notification.interceptor';
import { SharedModule, UserRouteAccessService } from './shared';
import { AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';
import { AccountModule } from './account/account.module';
import { EntityModule } from './entities/entity.module';
import { PaginationConfig } from './blocks/config/uib-pagination.config';
import {
    MainComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ProfileService,
    PageRibbonComponent,
    ActiveMenuDirective,
    ErrorComponent
} from './layouts';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
        HomeModule
        EntityModule,
        ChartModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        MainComponent,
        NavbarComponent,
        ErrorComponent,
        PageRibbonComponent,
        ActiveMenuDirective,
        FooterComponent,
        ChartsComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        ProfileService,
        PaginationConfig,
        UserRouteAccessService,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AuthInterceptor,
            multi: true,
            deps: [
                LocalStorageService,
                SessionStorageService
            ]
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AuthExpiredInterceptor,
            multi: true,
            deps: [
                Injector
            ]
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: ErrorHandlerInterceptor,
            multi: true,
            deps: [
                EventManager
            ]
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: NotificationInterceptor,
            multi: true,
            deps: [
                Injector
            ]
        },
        /*{
            provide: NgbDateParserFormatter,
            useFactory: () => { return new NgbDateMomentParserFormatter("DD-MM-YYYY") }
        }*/
    ],
    bootstrap: [ MainComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I think that's all what's relevant, if someone could explain what's wrong, missing and why, it would be of great help. In the meanwhile I'll try to document myself better on the module/import system.

Comment: Can we see your app.module.ts please?

Comment: In your `charts.module.ts`, shouldn't `import { ChartsComponent } from './';` be `import { ChartsComponent } from './charts.component';` ?

Comment: oh! I've just added the app.module.ts section, but I'll try that out blueprintChris

Comment: let me know if you have any luck

Comment: Update: It didn't work.

Comment: We worked it out, I'll post the solution during the evening. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent news, would love to see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically, the module.ts file in which you are going to import the ChartsComponent and the ChartModule (we are talking highcharts here) needs to also export ChartsComponent.

Import both, then under NgModule import ChartModule, and under declarations and exports tag ChartsComponent. On the destination data.module import ChartsComponent and tag it under NgModule - entryComponents. On the destination DataComponent import ChartsComponent.